# Errors building XScreensaver for X11 (and dependencies) on Mac

Tags: osx, glib

I'm building XScreensaver (the X11 version) on Mac OSX and I get the following errors while building/compiling it and its deps.

#### XScreensaver

```
terences-imac:xscreensaver-5.21 MAU$ make
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include alpha.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from alpha.c:16:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include colors.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from colors.c:16:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include fade.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from fade.c:12:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include grabscreen.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from grabscreen.c:33:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include grabclient.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from grabclient.c:21:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include hsv.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from hsv.c:16:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include overlay.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from overlay.c:58:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include resources.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from resources.c:13:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include spline.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from spline.c:27:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include usleep.c
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include visual.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from visual.c:20:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include visual-gl.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from visual-gl.c:23:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include xmu.c
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include logo.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from logo.c:22:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include yarandom.c
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include erase.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from erase.c:18:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include xshm.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from xshm.c:33:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include xdbe.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from xdbe.c:18:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include colorbars.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from colorbars.c:16:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include minixpm.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from minixpm.c:34:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-overlength-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -no-cpp-precomp -c -I. -I..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr/X11/include textclient.c
In file included from /usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:47,
                 from utils.h:24,
                 from textclient.c:21:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xfuncproto.h:136:24: warning: ISO C does not permit named variadic macros
/bin/sh ./../utils/ad2c XScreenSaver.ad > XScreenSaver_ad.h
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
make[1]: *** [XScreenSaver_ad.h] Error 1
make: *** [default] Error 5
```

#### GDK Pixbuf:

```
terences-imac:gdk-pixbuf-2.29.0 MAU$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking for native Win32... no
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... no
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin12.3.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.lt
config.lt: creating libtool
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking dependency style of gcc -std=gnu99... gcc3
checking for some Win32 platform... no
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for BASE_DEPENDENCIES... no
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.37.0) were not met:

Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.37.0' but version of GLib is 2.30.3

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

#### GLIB

```
make  all-recursive
Making all in .
Making all in m4macros
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in glib
  GEN      glibconfig-stamp
config.status: executing glib/glibconfig.h commands
config.status: glib/glibconfig.h is unchanged
make  all-recursive
Making all in libcharset
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in pcre
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in update-pcre
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in .
echo glib-unix.h glib-object.h glib.h galloca.h garray.h gasyncqueue.h gatomic.h gbacktrace.h gbase64.h gbitlock.h gbookmarkfile.h gbytes.h gcharset.h gchecksum.h gconvert.h gdataset.h gdate.h gdatetime.h gdir.h genviron.h gerror.h gfileutils.h ggettext.h ghash.h ghmac.h ghook.h ghostutils.h gi18n.h gi18n-lib.h giochannel.h gkeyfile.h glist.h gmacros.h gmain.h gmappedfile.h gmarkup.h gmem.h gmessages.h gnode.h goption.h gpattern.h gpoll.h gprimes.h gqsort.h gquark.h gqueue.h grand.h gregex.h gscanner.h gsequence.h gshell.h gslice.h gslist.h gspawn.h gstdio.h gstrfuncs.h gtestutils.h gstring.h gstringchunk.h gthread.h gthreadpool.h gtimer.h gtimezone.h gtrashstack.h gtree.h gtypes.h gunicode.h gurifuncs.h gutils.h gvarianttype.h gvariant.h gversion.h gversionmacros.h gwin32.h gprintf.h > glib-public-headers.txt.tmp && mv glib-public-headers.txt.tmp glib-public-headers.txt
Making all in tests
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in gmodule
make  all-am
  CC       libgmodule_2_0_la-gmodule.lo
  CCLD     libgmodule-2.0.la
Making all in gthread
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in gobject
make  all-recursive
Making all in .
  GEN      gobject-public-headers.txt
Making all in tests
make  all-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in gio
  GEN      gioenumtypes.h
  GEN      gioenumtypes.c
make  all-recursive
Making all in gdbus-2.0/codegen
  GEN      gdbus-codegen
Making all in xdgmime
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in kqueue
  CC       libkqueue_la-gkqueuedirectorymonitor.lo
  CC       libkqueue_la-kqueue-helper.lo
  CC       libkqueue_la-kqueue-exclusions.lo
  CCLD     libkqueue.la
Making all in .
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gasynchelper.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gconverterinputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gconverteroutputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gcredentials.lo
gcredentials.c:88:2: warning: #warning Please add GCredentials support for your OS
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdatainputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdataoutputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdummyfile.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gemblem.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gfile.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gfileenumerator.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gfilemonitor.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gicon.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-ginetaddress.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-ginetaddressmask.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-ginetsocketaddress.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-ginputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-giomodule.lo
giomodule.c: In function '_g_io_modules_ensure_extension_points_registered':
giomodule.c:960: warning: 'g_desktop_app_info_lookup_get_type' is deprecated (declared at gdesktopappinfo.h:124)
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gmemoryinputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gmemoryoutputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gmountoperation.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gnetworkaddress.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gnetworking.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gnetworkmonitor.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gnetworkservice.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-goutputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gpollableinputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gpollableoutputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gpollableutils.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gproxyaddressenumerator.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gresolver.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsocket.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsocketaddress.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsocketclient.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsocketconnection.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsocketcontrolmessage.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsocketinputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsocketoutputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsocketservice.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gsimpleproxyresolver.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gthreadedresolver.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gtlsbackend.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gtlsclientconnection.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gtlsconnection.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gtlsinteraction.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gtlspassword.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gtlsserverconnection.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gzlibcompressor.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gzlibdecompressor.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gioenumtypes.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdesktopappinfo.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gfiledescriptorbased.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixconnection.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixcredentialsmessage.lo
gunixcredentialsmessage.c: In function 'g_unix_credentials_message_serialize':
gunixcredentialsmessage.c:189: warning: unused variable 'message'
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixfdlist.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixfdmessage.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixmount.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixmounts.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixsocketaddress.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixvolume.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixvolumemonitor.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixinputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gunixoutputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gapplication.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gapplicationcommandline.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gapplicationimpl-dbus.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusaddress.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusauthobserver.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusauth.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusauthmechanism.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusauthmechanismanon.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusauthmechanismexternal.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusauthmechanismsha1.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbuserror.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusconnection.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusmessage.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusproxy.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusprivate.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusmethodinvocation.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusserver.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusinterfaceskeleton.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gdbusobjectmanagerclient.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-gtestdbus.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-glocaldirectorymonitor.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-glocalfile.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-glocalfileinputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-glocalfilemonitor.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-glocalfileoutputstream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-glocalfileiostream.lo
  CC       libgio_2_0_la-glocalvfs.lo
  CCLD     libgio-2.0.la
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib
  CCLD     gio-querymodules
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib
  CC       gvdb-builder.o
  CC       glib-compile-schemas.o
  CCLD     glib-compile-schemas
  CC       glib-compile-resources.o
  CCLD     glib-compile-resources
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib
  CC       gsettings-tool.o
  CCLD     gsettings
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib
  CC       gdbus-tool.o
  CCLD     gdbus
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib
  CC       gresource-gresource-tool.o
  CCLD     gresource
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libffi.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/libintl.dylib
  GEN      gio-public-headers.txt
Making all in tests
dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double
  Referenced from: /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double
  Referenced from: /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double
  Referenced from: /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double
  Referenced from: /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
  GEN      gdbus-test-codegen-generated.c
  GEN      test_resources.c
dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double
  Referenced from: /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/MAU/Downloads/glib-2.37.1/gobject/.libs/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
/bin/sh: line 1: 83097 Trace/BPT trap: 5       ../../gio/glib-compile-resources --target=test_resources.c --sourcedir=. --generate-source --c-name _g_test1 test2.gresource.xml
make[4]: *** [test_resources.c] Error 133
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: We're you able to try out my suggestion?

Comment: FYI if you don't allocate your bounty it will evaporate. There is still 22 hours of grace period so if the solution I've provided isn't acceptable we have a little time to try looking for other options.

Comment: That first Xscreensaver error `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` looks like is caused by different `sed` implementation assumed by some script.  I guess it's assuming GNU sed, while you have BSD sed of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what's tripping you up so that you can't compile XScreenSaver on OSX but if you just want to install it you can download the .dmg file from this site which contains it already pre-built as a binary.

http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/download.html

You might want to try asking your question on [jwz.org's forums](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/bugs.html) given he's been successful in compiling XScreenSaver for OSX. There's also a [FAQ](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html) available on the site too. Also here's the [link to the main page](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/).